# preg_replace replacing allowed characters

Tags: php, database, post, preg-replace

I am using `preg_replace` to replace any characters put in the form that I do not want, I have tried reading up on `preg_replace` but many of the examples I have looked at are not very clear.

In my code below I am using `[^a-z` etc... to say what characters are allowed and then the `''` is what it should replace any characters that are not allowed with, but my code was not working so I echoed out the `INSERT` function which should of been entering user data into the database and most fields are being replaced with `''`. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks, only the `c` and `e` variables are being inserted to database, `e` because it is not using `preg_replace` and `c` is a drop down list, the `u` `p` also work but everything else is replaced by `' '` for example I put the first name as joe and last name as wayne but when I look at the echo statement they are `' '`

```
  $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
  $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
  $p = $_POST['p'];
  $ln = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['lastName']);
  $fn = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['firstName']);
  $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['g']);
  $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
  $m = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST['m']);
  $ci = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#i', '', $_POST['ci']);
  $pc = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['pc']);
  $rs = $_POST['relationshipStatus'];
  $d = $_POST['d'];
```

Comment: what does echo $e or echo $ci  give you?

Comment: I am using this on a form and when I echo $e it gives me the email address I entered and when I echo $c it displays the country I selected from the drop down list but every thing else I enter seems to be replaced with ''

Comment: Have you verified that `$_POST['u']` is not empty when it gets to the server?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question `u` and `p` also work but thats it

Comment: Have you verified that `$_POST['lastName']` is not empty when it gets to the server?

Comment: the only way I have checked it is by echoing out the mysql INSERT function to see what data is attempting to be passed to the database and even though in the form I put a name it shows that `'lastName'` is blank if I do not echo the statement out nothing at all gets put into the database because the primary key is missing because it has been replaced

Comment: Is there a good *business* reason you're mangling your data like this?

Comment: Slow down cowboy! `phpinfo()` is your friend here. It will confirm that all the `$_POST` are set as you expect. Perhaps your form is not correct or the program is doing something later on but before the insert to blank out the lastName. You'll have to track where it becomes blank.

Comment: just to make sure that accurate data is inserted into the database

Comment: @Joey93: You're kinda doing the opposite, though.  Anyone with an accented character in their name is gonna be in for a shock.  As is anyone with a last name like "de la Hoya".  And a million other cases.  The most accurate personal data will be the data as entered by the user.

Comment: @cHao ok thanks for the advice I will change the first name and last name fields and have no restriction on them

Comment: @DavidNewcomb this may sound stupid< I am new to php but how would I use `phpinfo()`

Comment: @Joey93: Just stick it at or near the top of the script your form posts to.  (You may also want to `exit` after, for sanity's sake.  You're not really looking to see the script working at that point; the goal is just to see the output that `phpinfo()` generates.)  Or create a new page and point your form there for testing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

The following code:

```
<?php
$x = "heLlo World";
$y = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $x);
echo "y=$y|";
?>
```

produces:

```
y=heLloWorld|
```

So your expressions look ok to me. You'll have to verify that your subjects are not empty when they get to the server end.

Comment: `^` is negation in a character class.